# Display custom option in Images gallery android

Tags: android, image

Im developing a camera app that send images to a server, when user take a pic, the image is saved and send to the server. Now the custumer asked me that there must be a resend option in case of failure of whare ever reason.

How can i add a custom action in the gallery app so that when user press the menu can see a option that says:  "Resend image with xxx app "?

Its like [picasa, google + does](http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2013/10/Android-ICS-Gallery.png). I'd like to add my own option there.

How is this possible? Some guide will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add Intent filter for that purpose. When u'll add intent filter your app will receive data of which you are listening. From gallery we have  receive multiple or single option.You can see the link http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

```
   <activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. But, do you know how can i get the image or even the selected image path? When i select the image and select my app i get a url that does not exists. The image is in DIMC/Camera/ folder in SD card but it send content://file/images/someRandonNumber.

Comment: @JustannormalUser you need to execute query with contentresolver as it is returning content uri.